# wrapper for command in windows, system wide available

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, cmd

What I am trying to do, is create wrapper for `git clone` command on windows 10.
I want to have retry, if git clone fails.

I have git installed on the machine. I want to redirect the command `git clone` to my custom script, that would execute it, as many times as needed and return the output.
pseudocode:

```
if command == "git clone":
    ./gitwrapper.ps1
```

How do I connect this `command` with calling the wrapper script? Is there something in windows like linux alias?

Comment: Please use the command `DOSKEY /?` to see if it will do what you want.

Comment: I got it sorted but there is another issue with git plugin credentials...